# Removing child node from html document jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var ff = "<div class='ofr-test'><h3>My test</h3><div class='ban--content'><strong>Only a Test</strong><p>Blah Blah</p><p id='first' class='red'>Blah2 Blah2 Blah2</p></div></div>"

$(ff).find('.first').remove().end().html();
```

Works correctly, but the parent `div(class=‘ofr-test’)` is being removed, how can I fix it?

---

Comment: Have you noticed that your string is not well formed?

Comment: You need to use different quotes. You JavaScript variable is `var ff = "<div class="`, followed by a syntax error. Also, your selector is invalid.

Comment: it’s a mistake in my original string I use single quotes inside the double quotes... not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var ff = ".ofr-test"

$(ff).find('#first').remove().end().html();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ofr-test'>
  <h3>My test</h3>
  <div class='ban--content'>
  <strong>Only a Test</strong>
  <p>Blah Blah</p>
  <p id='first' class='red'>Blah2 Blah2 Blah2</p></div></div>
```

You are having a id named first not a class more over use the above syntax to select a node its more readable.Although I'm not sure why whole div is being used in your case but its not a good option whatsoever

Comment: Maybe i’m not clear enough :-), the string is being loaded dynamically it must be parsed to HTML, this is the reason i’m using $(ff)

Comment: Blah2 Blah2 Blah2 is not there in the output just see it

Comment: I was able to remove Blah2 blah2 as well, but I was losing the parent div(ofr-test) and I need it!

Comment: ofr-test is still there inspect it

Comment: Try to load the string and parse it!